# How to make a form unbound bound?

Tags: django, forms, validation

how to make the instance passed as a parameter make the form always valid?
I want to modify an tuple which is in database.

```
ue   = UE.objects.get(code_ue='INF401')
>>>ue_form = UEForms(instance=ue)
>>>ue_form.is_valid()
False
```

Here is views.py

```
def modifier_ue(request, code):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        ue_form = UEForms(request.POST);
        if ue_form.is_valid() and 'supprimer' in request.POST:
                return HttpResponse('supprimer');

        elif ue_form.is_valid() and 'continuer' in request.POST:
            return HttpResponse('continuer');


        elif ue_form.is_valid() and 'quitter' in request.POST:
            return HttpResponse('quitter');


        else:
            return HttpResponse(ue_form.errors.as_data())


    else:
        ue      = UE.objects.get(code_ue=code);
        ue_form = UEForms(instance=ue);
        return render(request, 'felyn/admin/modifier_ue.html', {'ue_form': ue_form, 'code': code});
```

Comment: you set `data=QueryDict()`

Comment: I don't see why you want to make your form bounded here. In a `GET` request, you typically do not make the form bounded, since, well, the POST needs to bound the form. So in the GET case, it is typically just `UEForms(isntance=ue)`...

Answer (score 1):

A `Form` is bound given the `data` is not `None`, or `files` is not `None`. Indeed, in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/forms/forms.py#L77), we see:

> ```
> class BaseForm:
>
>     # ...
>
>     def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
>                  initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
>                  empty_permitted=False, field_order=None, use_required_attribute=None, renderer=None):
>         self.is_bound = data is not None or files is not None
>         # ...
> ```

So we only need to pass something to `data` here, for example an empty [**`QueryDict`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). `request.POST` is a `QueryDict`, so here we basically construct one for the form:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

ue_form = UEForms(QueryDict(), instance=ue)
```

Comment: Not only does it not work and it generates errors in other parts of my code. I already have read QueryDict in the doc, it dont help me. 

Comment: @fogangfokoa: well perhaps it might be helpful to specify the errors. The fact that a form is not valid, is probably due to the fact that some of your form fields are *required*, so then evidently the form is *bounded*, but not valid.

Comment: Error is __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: @fogangfokoa: that is likely because your `UEForms` is not a `ModelForm`, or well the thing you call with `instance=...`. Note that a `Form` itself has no `instance`, since, well, it does not work with models.

Comment: It's ModelForms, class UEForms(forms.ModelForm):

Comment: @fogangfokoa: are you sure the error is thrown when you create that form? By looking at the traceback, what object you are `__init__`ing.

Comment: Here is code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094980/inconsistent-redirect

Comment: I edit my post. My goal is to modify an tupe which is into database

Comment: @fogangfokoa: can you please post the *full* traceback (so all the calls from the middleware up to the call).

Comment: @fogangfokoa: you do not *need* to *patch* the `__init__` function. I am only pointing out where it is handled in the Django code. So you can remove the `__init__` in your `UEForms` class.

Comment: @fogangfokoa: please see [a tutorial on working with `ModelForm`s](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/) that shows the corresponding view logic.

Comment: it does not help me. it's frustrating and annoying. is the method with __init___ the only method?

Comment: @fogangfokoa: you still do not get it. You don't need to overwrite the `__init__`. The only thing you need to do is change the `UEForms(instance=ue)` to `UEForms(QueryDict(), instance=ue)`, so revert these changes. But that being said, the view really shows a lot of problems, it is not how a view is supposed to look like.

Comment: how would you proceed if you want to change a tuple of the database via a form ?

Comment: @fogangfokoa: you create the form with `UEForms(request.POST, instance=ue)`, and then after `form.is_valid()` holds, you can `form.save()`. This of course when you trigger the view with a POST method.

Comment: It's posssible (UEForms(request.POST, instance=ue))? I thinks no.

Comment: @fogangfokoa: this is even a standard-case in the standard documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method However based on the question text and this discussion, I think you really first need to make yourself familiar with some basic HTTP and Django concepts. Without some fundamental understanding, it will be very hard to actually construct something.